# Thick line separating two views in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-attribute

> I want this:

[image]

> I have this:

[image]

I tried using elevation attribute but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Elevation works on views for lollipop and plus (API 21).
For achieving a divider like this you can simply add a view below your
layout with grey color as background.For ex:-

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can not work correctly on different screens:
android:layout_height="1dp"
I recomended to use 1xp instead